goquery replaces all self closing tags by open and closing tags
I am processing html contents with some custom elements which might be self-closing tags. Below is the example:
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\"><en-note><div><br/></div><en-media hash=\"667676uy\" type=\"application/pdf\" /><ul style=\"--en-todo:true;\"><li style=\"--en-checked:false;\"><div>test todoist</div></li></ul><div><br/></div><div><br/></div></en-note>

I have been trying to do it using goquery
doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(bytes.NewReader([]byte(content)))

and after processing it, when I try to get the updated html using doc.Html() I am getting the below output:
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\"><en-note><div><br/></div><en-media hash=\"667676uy\" type=\"application/pdf\"><ul style=\"--en-todo:true;\"><li style=\"--en-checked:true;\"><div>Otra prueba de Todoist</div></li></ul><div><br/></div><div><br/></div></en-media></en-note>

In my original html, I had en-media self-closing tag but in my output html, it got nested elements.
Note: I am not updating self-closing tags.
Any help would be appreciated.

This looks very similar to what will happen to a "self-closing" div. There actually is no such thing, so any browser that will try to render one will auto-correct the error and it does so by wrapping the div around any content that follows.

So there is no way to prevent it or is there any to do some like  to  without any elements in it?
